# Linux can not find gitlab-rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitlab

So I try to do a backup of git. I have found this script (here:https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md)
But if I use this command it says that the command is not found. What am I doing wrong?

```
root@gitlab-test git/gitlab# sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create SKIP=db,uploads                                                                                                            
    sudo: gitlab-rake: command not found
```

Also I tried the command

`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production`

But with that the command stopped at `upload.rb` with a `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends where gitlab is installed.
For example:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/gitlab/bin
export PATH
```

Check if `gitlab-rake` is there in `/opt/gitlab/bin`.

[There should be symlinks in /usr/bin](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/merge_requests/331).
If not, maybe you have installed GitLab from source (`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake`)

Comment: From source: maybe a symlink issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/899#note_2558643